# Progress bar not changing

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, repaint

I'm aware of all the other similar questions but i cannot seem to fix the problem. I've tried "bar.repaint();" and "bar.update(bar.getGraphics());" but none of them seems to work.

If anyone has time to take a quick look at it i'd really appreciate it! It's really bugging me, i've been trying to solve it for hours now.

It's basically a shutdown timer. You input hours and seconds and it counts down until it shuts down the computer. It also has a progressbar, which is the problem. It doesn't seem to want to repaint itself after each second.

It's a lot of code, so i decided to just upload all of the files (2 files).

speedyshare.com/files/29072975/files.zip

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Snippet of the code that isn't working:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    try{
        if(varHours.getText() != null && varMins.getText() != null){
            Thread countDownThread = new Thread(new Countdown(Integer.parseInt(varHours.getText()), Integer.parseInt(varMins.getText())));
            int totalSecs = (Integer.parseInt(varHours.getText())*60*60) + (Integer.parseInt(varMins.getText())*60);
            shutdownProgress = new javax.swing.JProgressBar(0, totalSecs);
            countDownThread.start();
        }else{
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please supply both fields!", "One or more fields were not supplied", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!\nCould not launch method countDown!", "Error!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
```

Comment: Please post a simplified portion of your code here so we can view it without going to the link you posted.

Comment: Have a look over this [CountDownProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931933/how-to-make-timer-countdown-along-with-progress-bar/5932222#5932222) for tips.  It is a complete example in less than 40 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

In `jButton1ActionPerformed` you set `shutdownProgress`. However, this is a new JProgressBar, not the one created in `initComponents()`. So, any changes you later make to `shutdownProgress` are made to a JProgressBar that is not displayed.

Secondly, making changes to a Swing component from a thread other than the EDT is a major no-no.
Use [SwingUtilitities .invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).