# How to use the Swing Timer to delay the loading of a progress bar

Tags: java, swing, timer, progress-bar, sleep

I need to find a way to use the Swing Timer with a progress bar. I tried using Thread.sleep(), but it crashed the app when I used it. Any ways to use the Swing Timer instead of the Sleep()?

```
public void piiEros(int dist)
{
    Pii pii = new Pii();
    pii.setVisible(true);
    for(int pc = 0;100 > pc; pc++)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(dist/100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Trav.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        pii.pg.setValue(pc);
    }
    pii.dispose();
    o.Eros();
}
```

NOTES: Pii is a class with th Progress Bar. Dist is the speed at which it loads. Trav is the class the method is in. Pc stands for %, how much is done is displyed on the bar. o.Eros opens anotherr GUI.

Comment: Sorry about the code, the spaces just delete themselves. EDIT:Eng Fouad fixed the indents, thanks!

Comment: Here is a more readable code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/402vcqi3ah4kcbn/ST%20PG.JPG

Comment: Do not sleep on EDT! Btw, when it comes to progress bar, use SwingWorker.

Comment: Probably better to use a SwingWorker

Comment: Also see [Getting my jProgressBar to run on a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11918384/1048330)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easier (in the long run) to use a `SwingWorker`.  It supplies a number of useful methods for updating the UI (from the context of the Event Dispatching Thread) while allowing to continue executing in the background...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestSwingWorker02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSwingWorker02();
    }

    public TestSwingWorker02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
            add(pb);

            new ProgressWorker(pb, 40).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private int delay;
        private JProgressBar pb;

        public ProgressWorker(JProgressBar progressBar, int delay) {
            this.pb = progressBar;
            this.delay = delay;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            // Back in the EDT...
            pb.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)); // only care about the last one...
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                publish(index);
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // Back in the EDT...
            //pii.dispose();
            //o.Eros();
        }

    }

}
```

The `SwingWorker` allows you to separate the logic.  In the `doInBackground` method you can focus on that part of the code that needs to operate outside the EDT, you can `publish` updates back to the EDT and `process` them separately.  When it's all `done` you can clean up as required.

`SwingWorker` also provides a progress monitoring functionality, so, in your case, this would you wouldn't have to use the `publish`/`process` portion of the API if you didn't want to.  This would allow you to attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to a the worker without the need to expose the progress bar to it.  (But I did for the example)

```
public class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    private int delay;
    private JProgressBar pb;

    public ProgressWorker(JProgressBar progressBar, int delay) {
        this.pb = progressBar;
        this.delay = delay;
        // You can use a property change listener to monitor progress updates...
        addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    pb.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
            setProgress(index);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // Back in the EDT...
        //pii.dispose();
        //o.Eros();
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for modern and clean answer..;) . But don't you think that for such small task `SwingWorker` is quite big one.

Comment: Personally, I find it cleaner and easier to follow (but I'm simple like that)

Comment: I see..Programmer's own taste..;)

Answer (score 2):

you can change your `piiEros` method in this way:

```
public void piiEros(int dist)
{
    final Pii pii = new Pii();
    pii.setVisible(true);
    javax.swing.Timer  timer = new javax.swing.Timer(dist/100, new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
      {
        pii.pg.setValue(pg.getValue()++);
        if ( pii.pg.getValue() > 100 )
        {
          timer.stop();
          pii.dispose();
          o.Eros();
        }
      }
    });
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: (No need to call `setDelay`, you've already established in the constructor ;))

Comment: Yeah, I like to be sure to ;)

Comment: The IDE doesn't like the javax.swing.Timer to be called in the method and I always add the name of the object I want to create before, so now it looks like this: Timer timer = new Timer(dist/100, new ActionListener()

Comment: Could'nt get your point..do you mean that Your IDE is complaining when it is seeeing `javax.swing.Timer` ?