# I can't see the JFrame components until the end of dataset mapping. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, neo4j, threadpool

I have developed a piece of software that creates an Ontology using neo4j. Once the ontology is built, I start mapping the dataset of 2 million rows to it, which takes more or less 20 minutes to be completed. As a result, I wished to add a JFrame that shows the process execution. The code below creates at the beginning the JFrame and then it starts mapping the dataset. However, I can see during the execution the JFrame, but its components appears inside the JFrame after the mapping finishes. I have read that the problem might be due to the lack of a thread that surrounds the code. Can anyone help me in solving this matter??

```
void createGraphDataset(String [][] choices , final ArrayList<String[]> DatabaseFile, GraphDatabaseService BORO_DB){

        JFrame converterFrame = new JFrame();
        converterFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        converterFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 650, 288);

                    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setVisible(true);
        converterFrame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);

        JPanel panelNeo1 = new JPanel();
        panelNeo1.setBounds(6, 6, 638, 254);
        panelNeo1.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(panelNeo1);
        panelNeo1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel labelNeo1 = new JLabel("CSV BORO Converter");
        labelNeo1.setBounds(16, 19, 260, 37);
        panelNeo1.add(labelNeo1);
        labelNeo1.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panelNeo2 = new JPanel();
        panelNeo2.setBounds(16, 60, 605, 167);
        panelNeo1.add(panelNeo2);
        panelNeo2.setLayout(null);
        panelNeo2.setVisible(true);

        /*
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setBounds(27, 89, 547, 20);
        panelNeo2.add(progressBar);
        panelNeo2.setVisible(true);
        */

        JLabel labelNeo2 = new JLabel(" Processing: Number of row");
        labelNeo2.setOpaque(true);
        labelNeo2.setBounds(28, 36, 184, 20);
        panelNeo2.add(labelNeo2);
        labelNeo2.setVisible(true);

        JLabel labelNeo3 = new JLabel("");
        labelNeo3.setBounds(212, 36, 76, 20);
        panelNeo2.add(labelNeo3);
        labelNeo3.setVisible(true);

        JLabel labelNeo4 = new JLabel();
        labelNeo4.setText(String.valueOf(DatabaseFile.size()));
        labelNeo4.setBounds(311, 36, 70, 20);
        panelNeo2.add(labelNeo4);
        labelNeo4.setVisible(true);

        JLabel labelNeo6 = new JLabel("of");
        labelNeo6.setBounds(288, 36, 23, 20);
        panelNeo2.add(labelNeo6);
        labelNeo6.setVisible(true);

        converterFrame.setVisible(true);



        TopNode= new Node [DatabaseFile.get(0).length];


        //Create TopNodes
        Transaction tx0 = BORO_DB.beginTx();
            try{

                for(int u =0; u<DatabaseFile.get(0).length;u++){

                        TopNode[u]=BORO_DB.createNode();
                        TopNode[u].setProperty("name", choices[u][0]);

                }

                tx0.success();

            }
            finally{

                tx0.finish();

            }

        //Create the database 
        for(int i =0; i<DatabaseFile.size();i++){

        Transaction tx2 = BORO_DB.beginTx();

            try
            {

                // Nodes for each row
                Node []graphNode= new Node [DatabaseFile.get(i).length];

                // Relationships for each row ingoing
                Relationship [] graphRelOn = new Relationship [DatabaseFile.get(i).length-1];

                // Relationships for each row outgoing
                Relationship [] graphRelOut = new Relationship [DatabaseFile.get(i).length-1];

                //Relationship to TopNode ingoing
                Relationship TopNodeRelIn[]=new Relationship [DatabaseFile.get(i).length];


                            //Creates Nodes for row and relationship to TopNode

                            for(int j=0; j<DatabaseFile.get(i).length;j++){

                                    //Stores Database values
                                    String []ValuesRow =DatabaseFile.get(i);

                                    //Creates nodes for 1 row
                                    graphNode[j] = BORO_DB.createNode();
                                    graphNode[j].setProperty("name", ValuesRow[j]);

                                    //From row to TopNode Relationship (enter)
                                    TopNodeRelIn[j]=graphNode[j].createRelationshipTo(TopNode[j], RelTypes.typeInstances);
                                    TopNodeRelIn[j].setProperty("relationship-type", "typeInstances");  
                            }

                            //Creates Relationships

                            for(int k=0; k<(DatabaseFile.get(i).length)-1;k++){


                                    //Between same elements of the same row (left to right)
                                    graphRelOn[k]=graphNode[k].createRelationshipTo(graphNode[k+1], RelTypes.relatesTo);
                                    graphRelOn[k].setProperty("relationship-type", "relatesTo");

                                    //Between same elements of the same row (right to left)
                                    graphRelOut[k]=graphNode[(DatabaseFile.get(i).length)-1].createRelationshipTo(graphNode[(DatabaseFile.get(i).length)-(2+k)], RelTypes.relatesTo);
                                    graphRelOut[k].setProperty("relationship-type", "relatesTo");


                            }

                    tx2.success();
                }
        finally
        {
        tx2.finish();
        }        
        }   
    }
```

Comment: this question missing two important things, 1) an SSCCE, 2) AWT/Swing JComponents are designated to be reusable, then is there please any reasont to buil an new Whatever on runtime

Comment: You don't need to setVisible(true) every single component inside the frame. Just the JFrame itself.

Comment: @mKorbel 1) I am sorry for that, I know that it is a bit long but I don't know where the problem is and what is important and what is not (I am a Beginner). This is why I have pasted the entire code. 2) I don't understand that answer

Comment: @Kayaman I agree indeed. That is the result of having tried every way to solve the problem

Comment: 2nd. point, add all required JComponents on Apps startup, intialize, set default and not null value, on runtine only to set value, you may look at CardLayout

Comment: Also, don't do it all in a single transaction, commit it every 1000 inserts or so. Alternatively, have a look at the BatchInserters class...

Comment: @MichalBachman thank you for the advise, I have read about BatchInserter but in many says that it is not safe to upload nodes with it rather it is very fast. Am i right? This is a dissertation research and what I am trying to solve is a conceptual problem, and at the moment I am not wondering about efficiency but only about reliability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are right, your problem has to do with the problem that the Thread responsible for painting the components is blocked by your operation. However, explaining all aspects of multi-threaded programming is beyond the scope of a single answer.

As a workaround you can just delay the computation.

```
// setup the GUI
frame.setVisible(true);
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
      doYourHavyComputation();
    }
  });
```

This way your computation still runs within the same thread and blocks the UI but at a later time when the initial frame contents has been painted.

If you wanna do real background computation you have to study one or more tutorials about multi-threading to understand all the complications then try it and come back if you have more specific questions.

Comment: I have encapsulated the database computation within your function and it works well. Thank you very much indeed

Comment: `SwingWorker` would be be suitable, as that would not stop the entire UI while the `doYourHavyComputation` is running...

Comment: SwingWorker still requires to be aware of the multi-threading issues, e.g. if an event handler accesses the same data as the background computation.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that the problem might be due to the lack of a thread that
>   surrounds the code

Would be a suitable assumption.  Swing is a single threaded environment, which means, all interactions and updates to the UI are required to be made within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Equally in action or operation which blocks this thread will prevent the EDT from processing (amongst other things) paint requests.

While there are a number of possible solutions, the best suited to your needs is probably the `SwingWorker`.

This allows you to run lengthy operations in a background thread, but has a number of methods by which you can re-sync the out comes of these operations back to the EDT.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

How you use it will depend on your needs...

For example, you could simply "publish" the current row your are processing...

```
public class Generator<Node , Integer> {

    protected void process(List<Integer> rows) {
        // Back in the EDT
        int lastRow = rows.get(rows.size() - 1); // Only interested in the last one...
        // Update the UI...
    }

    protected Node  doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Node topNode = new Node [DatabaseFile.get(0).length];
        /*...*/
        publish(rowNumber);
        /*...*/
        return topNode;
    }

    public void done() {
        // Back in the EDT
        try {
            Node topNode = get(); // Get the result of the calculation...
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Or you could take advantage of the `SwingWorker`'s property change support and use it's in built `setProgress` method.

See...

- [JProgressBar isn't progressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020949/jprogressbar-isnt-progressing/12021971#12021971)
- [How to use the Swing Timer to delay the loading of a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668715/how-to-use-the-swing-timer-to-delay-the-loading-of-a-progress-bar/15669717#15669717)

For some examples.

These will ensure that whole you a processing your calculations, the UI remains responsive to your changes

Comment: `class TwoThread extends Thread{
           
      Thread t1 = new Thread(){
             public void run(){
                  
     }
      };
     // my second thread
     `Thread t2 = new Thread(){`
    ` public void run(){`
                
   ` }`
    ` };`
           
     `@Override  public void run() {`
               `t1.start();`
               `t2.start();`
           `}`
           
           
          `}`
         
          `TwoThread TT1 = new TwoThread();`
          `TT1.start();`

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have attached in the previous comment (I am still learning how to use the blog :) ) how I solved my problem calling two thread at the same time. I typed in the first run() method the jframe and in the second one my computation. Sorry I am not allowed to give you +1 I don't have enough reputation... you deserved it :)

Comment: Don't forget.  Swing requires you to update the UI only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Using `Thread` requires you to perform this synchronisation your self