# Java Gui empty frame

Tags: java, user-interface

I am currently developing a project with a genetic algorithm.
It works fine, I get the results I wants, so no problem on this side.
I displayed all the information in the console so I decided to create a GUI to improve the software.

I have two frames. One is a selection frame where you select your options for the run.
The other is a frame with a textArea. The purpose of this second frame is to display the information about the run in it. For both frame I used the MVC design pattern. It works fine, I have run some tests for the GUI and all is displayed normally.

Now the problem is when I try to integrate the two sides.
I launch my first frame in the main. Then it switch to the second frame and run the Genetic algorithm when the information are complete and the user clicked the OK button. I make verification of the information and let the button enabled false until it is correct ;).
In theory it is suppose to display the second frame empty then launch the GA then input text in the frame dunring the run with the MVC model.

The problem happens when I click the button, the second frame display partially. I mean I have the frame with the title and the red close button but there is nothing in it. I can move the frame with my mouse but if i click the red close button, nothing append, so I guess the frame is kind of freeze. The Ga run perfectly during this time. At the end of the
GA's run the rest of the frame appears with all the information that should have been input in it. So the Mvc model is working good. It is just the frame that don't display normally.

I use the following code :

```
    Vue2 vrga = new VueLorsRunGa(); //create the 2nd frame
    vue1.dispose(); //destroy the first one
    //code to run the GA
```

I am not use with the GUI so maybe I made it wrong and so I don't free something needed.

If we take it sequentially, the vue2 is supposed to be totally launch before the ga code is executed. But i read in a article that the GUI's things are managed in a special thread. And so it not suppose to be freeze by the GA ... The GA got its specific threads but I haven't done any for the GUI.

So if anyone had a idea where I can be wrong or how to managed to suppress my bug, it would be great :)

Thank you for help

Scyn

Comment: i feel lost reading this . I have done soemthing similar to what you describe here but couldnt fully grasp ur question . :(

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508085/i-cant-see-the-jframe-components-until-the-end-of-dataset-mapping-why/18508497

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running your code in the EDT thread (like directly from the actionPerformed method) which blocks other events being processed.

You should move long running operations out of the EDT thread