# How to Use JProgressBar on Button Click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jprogressbar

In gui there are two fields which add two numbers on button click and there is code logic to check if the fields are empty but what i want is when user click on the button it should display a progress bar according to milliseconds progress should go from 1 to 100 then it complete the task and auto reset the progress bar.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Progress pg = new Progress();


    }

}
```

```
public class Progress extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JTextField t3;
    private JButton b1;
    private JProgressBar bar;
    Timer t;
    int interval = 1000;
    int i = 0;

    public Progress() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        t1 = new JTextField(20);
        t2 = new JTextField(20);
        t3 = new JTextField(20);

        b1 = new JButton("OK");
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        t = new Timer(interval, this);

        bar = new JProgressBar();
        bar.setStringPainted(true);
        bar.setValue(0);

        add(t1);
        add(t2);
        add(t3);
        add(b1);
        add(bar);

        setSize(600, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == b1) {

            if (t1.getText().isEmpty() || t2.getText().isEmpty()) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty Fields");
            }

            else {
                int w = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                int x = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                int res = w + x;
                t3.setText("" + res);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. What's your question or problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Progress extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JTextField t3;
    private JButton b1;
    JProgressBar progressBar;
    int i = 0;

    public Progress() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        t1 = new JTextField(20);
        t2 = new JTextField(20);
        t3 = new JTextField(20);

        b1 = new JButton("OK");
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(1, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        progressBar.setBackground(Color.white);

        add(t1);
        add(t2);
        add(t3);
        add(b1);
        add(progressBar);

        setSize(600, 480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int i = 0;
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            if (t1.getText().isEmpty() || t2.getText().isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empty Fields");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                try {
                    while (i <= 100) {

                        int w = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                        int x = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                        int res = w + x;
                        t3.setText("" + res);

                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        progressBar.paintImmediately(0, 0, 200, 200);
                        progressBar.setValue(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.print("Exception =" + e1);
                }
                progressBar.setValue(0);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Progress p = new Progress();
        p.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Check if it helps...?

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please explain the changes that you did.

Comment: @Maximus Decimus Meridius when it click it does not perfom action at real seconds

Comment: @JohnDoe Hello John, i just helped you out to display progress bar, please update your logic as per your requirement.

Comment: @Maximus Decimus Meridius why you didn't use Timer

Comment: If nothing is entered in the two textfields `t1` and `t2`, the code displays the joptionpane 100 times. Also, you call `setvisible` twice. Once from main and once from the constructor.

Comment: @JohnDoe John,you can use timer also. This is for your reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668715/how-to-use-the-swing-timer-to-delay-the-loading-of-a-progress-bar

Comment: @CoolGuy Hello CoolGuy,It is just code modification in John's logic. He will modify it as per his requirement.

Comment: @CoolGuy yes the issue occur

Comment: @Maximus Decimus Meridius could you tell me what these two steps do.Thread.sleep(50); bar.paintImmediately(0, 0, 200, 200);

Comment: @JohnDoe(1) Thread.sleep(50) : It will cease the execution of current thread for specified milliseconds. (2) bar.paintImmediately(0,0,200,200) will paint the specified region in component.

Comment: @JohnDoe Hope , you are now clear with it ? I have modified the answer a bit.